# Find number of rows for each hour

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to display how many users my site gets for each hour of the day.  I've come up with this, it works but...

```
$time = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM track_log WHERE time>='{$date} 00:00:00' AND 
time<='{$date} 01:00:00'");
$hour = mysql_num_rows($time);
```

before I do this 23 more times is there a better way to get the results for each hour?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SELECT hour(`time`) as hour_of_day, count(*)
FROM track_log 
group by hour_of_day
```